# Weak consistency from asymptotic unbiasedness

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, proof-verification

What follows is a task from an old university course on estimation theory. I would like to know whether my solution is correct.

Let $(\mathbb{H}, \mathcal{H})$ be a measurable space, and let $\mathcal{W} = \{P_\gamma | \gamma \in \Gamma\}$ be a family of probability measures, with $\Gamma$ being an index set. $h: \Gamma \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function that should be estimated. Let $(T_n)$ be a sequence of estimators for $h$. We now define weak consistency and asymptotic unbiasedness:

$(T_n)$ is defined to be weakly consistent if for all $\varepsilon > 0, \gamma \in \Gamma$:
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P_\gamma(\{x \in \mathbb{H} | |T_n(x) - h(\gamma)| \geq \varepsilon \}) = 0
\end{equation*}
$(T_n)$ is defined to be asymptotically unbiased if for all $\gamma \in \Gamma$:
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E_\gamma(T_n) = h(\gamma)
\end{equation*}
We now consider an asymptotically unbiased sequence of estimators $S_n: \mathbb{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where for all $\gamma \in \Gamma$:
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} V_\gamma(S_n) = 0
\end{equation*}
It should be shown that $(S_n)$ is also weakly consistent for $h$.

My proof:
Let us first define the term $F_{\gamma,n}(t) := P_\gamma(x |(S_n - h(\gamma))^2 \geq t)$. It can be shown using the layer-cake theorem that
\begin{equation*}
E_\gamma((S_n - h(\gamma))^2) = \int_0^\infty F_{\gamma,n}(t) d \lambda(t)
\end{equation*}
We now consider the term
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E_\gamma((S_n - h(\gamma))^2) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^\infty F_{\gamma,n}(t) d \lambda(t)
\end{equation*} 
We can now show that the left-hand term approximates 0, since:
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E_\gamma((S_n - h(\gamma))^2) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E_\gamma((S_n - E_\gamma(S_n) + E_\gamma(S_n) - h(\gamma))^2)
\end{equation*} 
\begin{equation*}
= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E_\gamma((S_n - E_\gamma(S_n))^2) 
+ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 2 \cdot E_\gamma((S_n - E_\gamma(S_n))(E_\gamma(S_n) - h(\gamma)))
+ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E_\gamma((E_\gamma(S_n) - h(\gamma))^2)
\end{equation*}
In the sum at the end, the last two terms go to 0 because $(S_n)$ is asymptotically unbiased, and therefore $E_\gamma(S_n) \rightarrow h(\gamma)$. The first term is the variance of $S_n$ which also goes to 0 for $n \rightarrow \infty$ by definition of $(S_n)$.
Therefore, we have
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^\infty F_{\gamma,n}(t) d \lambda(t) = 0
\end{equation*}
It follows that $F_{\gamma,n}(t) = P_\gamma(x |(S_n - h(\gamma))^2 \geq t)$ must become arbitrary small for $n \rightarrow \infty$, and therefore that $(S_n)$ is weakly consistent.

Comment: Your proof is quite convoluted and hard to follow, I posted something simpler below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$ and $\gamma \in \Gamma$ be fixed.
For $n\geq 1$, note the inclusions 
$$\begin{aligned}
(|S_n-h(\gamma)|\geq \epsilon) &\subset \left(|S_n-E_\gamma(S_n)|+|E_\gamma(S_n)-h(\gamma)|\geq \epsilon\right)\\
&\subset \left(|S_n-E_\gamma(S_n)|\geq \frac{\epsilon}2\right) \cup \left(|E_\gamma(S_n)-h(\gamma)| \geq \frac{\epsilon}2 \right)
\end{aligned}$$
The event $\left(|E_\gamma(S_n)-h(\gamma)| \geq \frac{\epsilon}2 \right)$ is deterministic. It is equal to $\mathbb H$ if $|E_\gamma(S_n)-h(\gamma)| \geq \frac{\epsilon}2$, and $\emptyset$ otherwise. 
Thus 
$$\begin{aligned}P(|S_n-h(\gamma)|\geq \epsilon)
&\leq P\left(|S_n-E_\gamma(S_n)|\geq \frac{\epsilon}2\right) + P\left(|E_\gamma(S_n)-h(\gamma)| \geq \frac{\epsilon}2 \right) \\
&= P\left([S_n-E_\gamma(S_n)]^2\geq \frac{\epsilon^2}4\right) + 1_{|E_\gamma(S_n)-h(\gamma)| \geq \frac{\epsilon}2} \\
&\leq \frac{V_\gamma(S_n)}{\frac{\epsilon^2}4} + 1_{|E_\gamma(S_n)-h(\gamma)| \geq \frac{\epsilon}2}
\end{aligned}$$

Since $S_n$ is asymptotically unbiased, $1_{|E_\gamma(S_n)-h(\gamma)| \geq \frac{\epsilon}2}\xrightarrow[n\to \infty]{} 0$ and the conclusion follows.